# LINQ: Query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Tags: c#, linq

when i am executing my LINQ code then i am getting the error **A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause**

i very rarely use LINQ and that is the reason not being able to figure out what is the problem on code. so anyone could see my below LINQ code and guide me what is my mistake for which getting error.

```
    string[] csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    var query = from csvline in csvlines
    let data = csvline.Split(',').Skip(1)
    .Select(a => new User
    {
        CSRName = data[6],
        CallStart = data[0],
        CallDuration = data[1],
        RingDuration = int.Parse(data[2]),
        Direction = int.Parse(data[3]),
        IsInternal = int.Parse(data[4]),
        Continuation = int.Parse(data[5]),
        ParkTime = int.Parse(data[7])
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the top most row is header row. You are mixing query and method syntax here. You can write your query as shown below:

```
var query = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(x =>
        {
            var data = x.Split(',');

            return new User
            {
                CSRName = data[6],
                CallStart = data[0],
                CallDuration = data[1],
                RingDuration = int.Parse(data[2]),
                Direction = int.Parse(data[3]),
                IsInternal = int.Parse(data[4]),
                Continuation = int.Parse(data[5]),
                ParkTime = int.Parse(data[7])
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
var query = from csvline in csvlines
let data = csvline.Split(',').Skip(1)
```

Isn't valid LINQ syntax. It should be:

```
string csvlines = File.ReadAllText(filename);
var query = csvlines.Split(',')
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Select(data => new User
{
    CSRName = data[6],
    CallStart = data[0],
    CallDuration = data[1],
    RingDuration = int.Parse(data[2]),
    Direction = int.Parse(data[3]),
    IsInternal = int.Parse(data[4]),
    Continuation = int.Parse(data[5]),
    ParkTime = int.Parse(data[7])
}).ToList();
```

Comment: the code Split(',') giving error `System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array`

Comment: @Mou Didn't see it was an `IEnumerable<string>`. Edited my answer.

Comment: problem is still there.

Comment: @Mou Wait, You're looking for `ReadAllText`, not `ReadAllLines`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `Split(',')` is for a `string`, not a `string[]`

Comment: @Matt That's why I used `ReadAllText`, not `ReadAllLines`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov my mistake (and potentially the OP's too) :)

Comment: when i am running your code or matt code then i am getting error "Input string was not in a correct format." what could be the problem in code or data ? when i print data like  data[6] and saw it was "\"Account\"" data but should be Account rather

Comment: @Mou This means you're not parsing your data correctly. This is why you should use a 3rd party CSV parser, and not roll it on your own.

Comment: there was problem which i fixed. thanks to all for support